# Does dapper support .net dataset

Tags: dapper

in my opinion for dapper.query object there is a datareader, for dapper.Execute there is a ExectureNonQuery object. Correct me if i am wrong .

Can we use dapper for dataset which returns multiple tables?

Comment: I'm not sure I've interpreted your question correctly, but if you want to get multiple result sets from a single SQL command, take a look at QueryMultiple. There's an example in Dapper's site.

Comment: Like other ORM, the whole point using an ORM is to get away from the column/row mantra and use proper .NET objects instead. So now - I don't think Dapper does (or ever will) support datasets and datatables

Comment: So I am correct it is for datareader and executeNonQuery of ADO.net. what is the site for Dapper?  So far I am getting information about dapper from here and there.

Comment: Dapper does support multi-table queries, but it doesn't do it via DataTable / DataSet (indeed, if you want that: just use DataAdapter). Do you specifically want to use DataTable? Or is your main point here just "multiple tables"?

Comment: No I was trying to understand what is happening behind the scene when we are using dapper since I don't have much knowledge about it. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 13):

I might be late here but this is how I am doing the conversion of the `IDataReader` to a `DataSet`. `Dapper` returns a `IDataReader` when we use the `ExecuteReaderAsync` method. More information on this addition can be found [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/dapper-dot-net/issues/156) and [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/pull/103/commits/e53d85a0e2c872407f794777da2b395235e6aee3).

This is my attempt on this:

```
public async Task<DataSet> GetUserInformationOnUserId(int UserId)
{
    var storedprocedure = "usp_getUserInformation";
    var param = new DynamicParameters();
    param.Add("@userId", UserId);
    var list = await SqlMapper.ExecuteReaderAsync(_connectionFactory.GetEpaperDBConnection, storedprocedure, param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    var dataset = ConvertDataReaderToDataSet(list);
    return dataset;
}
```

And the `ConvertDataReaderToDataSet` will take in the `IDataReader`, you can use this method to convert the IReader to Dataset:

```
public DataSet ConvertDataReaderToDataSet(IDataReader data)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    int i = 0;
    while (!data.IsClosed)
    {
        ds.Tables.Add("Table" + (i + 1));
        ds.EnforceConstraints = false;
        ds.Tables[i].Load(data);
        i++;
    }                    
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: i use your method for my project, thank you

Answer (score 12):

No, there is not any built in support for `DataSet`, primarily because it seems largely redundant, but also because that isn't what dapper targets. But that doesn't mean it doesn't include an API for handling a query that `select`s multiple results; see `QueryMultiple`:

```
using (var multi = conn.QueryMultiple(sql, args))
{
    var ids = multi.Read<int>().ToList();
    var customers = multi.Read<Customer>().ToList();
    dynamic someOtherRow = multi.Read().Single();
    int qty = someOtherRow.Quantity, price = someOtherRow.Price;
}
```

Note that this API is forwards only (due to the nature of `IDataReader` etc) - basically, each `Read` / `Read<T>` etc maps to the next result grid in turn.